# WriteFile failure modes

Tags: windows, winapi, msxml

What can happen to a file that is being written to over a network share when the network connection "fails?"  I imagine multiple things can happen.

The reason I ask is because a program that I wrote appeared to corrupt a file in a way that I have never seen before.  Actually, I have never received a report of my program creating a corrupt file before, and I feel confident if it corrupted a file I would hear about it.  The code that that actually generated the corrupt file is actually Microsoft code.  The file is created when the `save` function is called on the IXMLDOMDocument2 interface from the MSXML4.0 COM component.  The function created an invalid XML document.  The last 5452 bytes of a 33789 byte file was filled with NULLs (0x00).  I'm trying to understand what happened.

Comment: The network connection failed while it was writing the file.  Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Hans, what are you saying?  Are you saying the behavior of write operations is undefined when the network connection fails?  Typically, networking stacks and/or network services have some sort of fault tolerance.

Comment: Looks like yours doesn't.  Take this to serverfault.com to find out, don't forget to carefully describe it.

Comment: @Hans, how is this a serverfault question?  This question is ultimately about the semantics of `WriteFile`.

Comment: No, WriteFile only generates an I/O request for a device driver.  What happens next is entirely dependent on what it does.  Your question cannot be answered because you didn't describe the system.

Comment: There might not have been a network failure.  I've seen some similar issues that appear to be due to a bug in the file sharing code in Windows 7 and/or 2008R2. If this is your problem, the easiest workaround I know of is to write the file to local disk and then copy it to the network share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that the file can be corrupted (as you've already found).

From there, nearly the only interesting question is how you prevent that from happening again. The typical way is to write the data to a temporary file, then after it's written rename it to the correct name. If the network connection dies in the middle of this, you won't have the correct file name. To recover, you delete any temporary files, and restart the operation from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I also found the following page helpful.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/12/28/507866.aspx